# Is there any 100% sure numerical method to find all roots in a polynomial equation of degree n without fail?

Tags: polynomials

Is there any 100% sure numerical method to find all roots in a polynomial equation of degree n without fail?
I do not find any method which solve polynomial equation without fail.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialRoots.html

Comment: The idea is that the roots are the eigenvalues of the companion matrix, and that we know how to computer the eigenvalues of a matrix numerically.

Comment: see also here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairstow's_method

Comment: Since in general there is no closed-expression for the roots of a high-degree polynomial, what do you mean by "finding" all the roots? Up to a prescribed precision? And what is a "fail"?